# Search strategies in Material Science

Tags: resource-recommendations, material-science

Material scientists often search for new materials with engineered properties. If, for example, you have a set of doped semiconducting materials with different doping levels, and you aim for maximal conductivity, the choice is straighforward -- try each of them, select the one which maximizes the conductivity. However, before you start that, you have to come up with possible base material, possible doping, possible coating, material production technique etc. -- a vast design parameter space to explore.

Is there a reference that summarizes and lists possible search strategies? Is there a rational way to search for novel materials?

I am aware of the general principles of [design of experiments](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Design_of_experiments), but if there are any principles that are specific to Material Science, please refer to them.

Comment: I've asked some professors at my doctoral program (not materials science, physics & astronomy) how they managed to find something interesting to publish (or get PhDs granted), most of the answers I've received involved words like "fortuitous" or "by accident" or "trial and error."

Comment: @KyleKanos, well, trial and error is definitely a possible search strategy, but not the only one on the table, I hope.

Comment: I strongly suspect that *experience* will help narrow directions/parameter spaces.

Comment: @KyleKanos, this means that with experience, a researcher develops his own strategies of search. While they can be intuition-based and hardly formalizable, I would expect at least one person to write down his thoughts on this.

Comment: Also possible, but it might be that no one has because not everyone performs research in the same way. I guess that I'm really trying to say "Don't get your hopes up & be willing to simply *explore* as the science & research lets you."

Comment: @KyleKanos, thanks a lot. The last part is possibly where the joy of research comes from.